# Rolling average over fixed time-window in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                   'val': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3],
                   'time': [pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 12), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 13), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 14), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 2, 16), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 2, 17), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 2, 18), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 12), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 13), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 14), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 15), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 16), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 2, 15), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 12), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 13), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 14), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 15), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 16), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 17), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 2, 18), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 2, 19), pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 2, 20)]})
```

I would like to create a new column giving, for each row, the average of `val` for all rows with the same `ID` within a 24 hour window before that row's `time`.

How can I do this in a pythonic way? As opposed to iterating over every row.

Expected output:

```
    ID  val                time  24hr_avg
0    1    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0 ###
1    1    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5  ##
2    1    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0   #
3    1    1 2017-01-02 16:00:00       1.0    ##
4    1    2 2017-01-02 17:00:00       1.5     ##
5    1    3 2017-01-02 18:00:00       2.0      #
6    2    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0       #####
7    2    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5        ####
8    2    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0         ###
9    2    4 2017-01-01 15:00:00       2.5          ###
10   2    5 2017-01-01 16:00:00       3.0           ##
11   2    6 2017-01-02 15:00:00       8.0            #
12   3    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0             ######
13   3    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5              #####
14   3    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0               ####
15   3    4 2017-01-01 15:00:00       2.5                ###
16   3    5 2017-01-01 16:00:00       3.0                 ##
17   3    6 2017-01-01 17:00:00       3.5                  #
18   3    1 2017-01-02 18:00:00       1.0                   ###
19   3    2 2017-01-02 19:00:00       1.5                    ##
20   3    3 2017-01-02 20:00:00       2.0                     #
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you `set_index` the time column first then you can use `groupby.rolling` with a window of 24H. then `merge` with the original data:

```
df_ = df.merge(df.set_index('time').sort_index()
                 .groupby('ID')
                 .rolling('24H')
                 ['val'].mean()
                 .rename('24hr_avg'), 
               left_on=['ID', 'time'], right_index=True)
print(df_)
    ID  val                time  24hr_avg
0    1    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0
1    1    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5
2    1    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0
3    1    1 2017-01-02 16:00:00       1.0
4    1    2 2017-01-02 17:00:00       1.5
5    1    3 2017-01-02 18:00:00       2.0
6    2    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0
7    2    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5
8    2    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0
9    2    4 2017-01-01 15:00:00       2.5
10   2    5 2017-01-01 16:00:00       3.0
11   2    6 2017-01-02 15:00:00       5.5
12   3    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0
13   3    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5
14   3    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0
15   3    4 2017-01-01 15:00:00       2.5
16   3    5 2017-01-01 16:00:00       3.0
17   3    6 2017-01-01 17:00:00       3.5
18   3    1 2017-01-02 18:00:00       1.0
19   3    2 2017-01-02 19:00:00       1.5
20   3    3 2017-01-02 20:00:00       2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `Groupby.rolling`:

```
df['24hr_avg'] = (
    df.set_index('time')
    .groupby('ID', sort=False)['val']
    .rolling('1D')
    .mean()
    .to_numpy()
)
```

```
    ID  val                time  24hr_avg
0    1    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0
1    1    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5
2    1    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0
3    1    1 2017-01-02 16:00:00       1.0
4    1    2 2017-01-02 17:00:00       1.5
5    1    3 2017-01-02 18:00:00       2.0
6    2    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0
7    2    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5
8    2    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0
9    2    4 2017-01-01 15:00:00       2.5
10   2    5 2017-01-01 16:00:00       3.0
11   2    6 2017-01-02 15:00:00       5.5
12   3    1 2017-01-01 12:00:00       1.0
13   3    2 2017-01-01 13:00:00       1.5
14   3    3 2017-01-01 14:00:00       2.0
15   3    4 2017-01-01 15:00:00       2.5
16   3    5 2017-01-01 16:00:00       3.0
17   3    6 2017-01-01 17:00:00       3.5
18   3    1 2017-01-02 18:00:00       1.0
19   3    2 2017-01-02 19:00:00       1.5
20   3    3 2017-01-02 20:00:00       2.0
```

Comment: Use `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` instead `.to_numpy()`

Comment: True, on the other hand, using merge on a timestamp will fail if there are duplicate time entries which will cause duplication. So the best way to approach this is to sort on  ID and time and then using this method.